# How do I meter external volume using a microphone (Swift Playgrouds)

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation

i was just wondering if there is a method to meter audio in swift playgrounds using microphone input. Ive tried playing around with AVFoundation however have not yet found a method to meter mic input in dB, only how to record and store audio. Does anyone have any solutions.